# Prove $x^n(y-z) + y^n(z-x) + z^n(x-y)$ is divisible by $(y-z)(z-x)(x-y)$

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I have to show that $$P(x, y, z) = x^n(y-z) + y^n(z-x) + z^n(x-y)$$

is always divisible by $Q(x, y, z) = (y-z)(z-x)(x-y)$ for $n$ greater than $1$ and I have no idea how to proceed.

-> I would try to prove they have common  *roots* but I don't even know what "to be a root" means on a problem like this so I tried to factor it and realized that this might not be the correct approach. Can someone help me ?

Comment: $P$ is a *alternating* function: $P(x,y,z)=-P(y,x,z)=-P(x,z,y)$ etc.

Comment: Can you show $P$ is divisible by $y-z$, Leonardo? by doing some simple algebraic manipulations, perhaps?

Comment: So it works just like one variable polynomials ? I show it is divisible by each irreducible factor ? If the answer is yes, my question was really stupid.

Comment: No, this is not stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic idea: If you let $Q(x,y,z) = P(x,y,z+ x)$, then you can verify directly that $Q(x,y,0) = 0$, which means $z$ factors $Q(x,y,z)$. In other words $Q(x,y,z) = zR(x,y,z)$ for some
polynomial $R(x,y,z)$. Hence $P(x,y,z) = Q(x,y,z-x) = (z - x)R(x,y,z-x)$. Thus
$P(x,y,z)$ has $z- x$ as a factor.

You can do the analogous steps to get the other two factors.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it suffices to show that $P(x,y,z)$ is divisible by each of the three factors $(x-y)$, $(y-z)$, and $(z-x)$.  However, justifying this properly requires the theory of Unique Factorization Domains, which is possibly outside the scope of the question.

One alternative path is to proceed by direct factoring.  This starts as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}  Q(x,y,z) & = x^n(y-z) + y^n(z-x) + z^n(x-y) \\
& = xy(x^{n-1}-y^{n-1}) + z(y^n-x^n)+z^n(x-y) \\
& = (x-y)(xy(x^{n-2}+yx^{n-3}+\ldots+y^{n-2})
-z(y^{n-1}+xy^{n-2}+\ldots+x^{n-1})+z^n)\;. \\
\end{align*}
$$
The next step is to explicitly factor $(xy(x^{n-2}+yx^{n-3}+\ldots+y^{n-2})
-z(y^{n-1}+xy^{n-2}+\ldots+x^{n-1})+z^n$ as $(y-z)R(x,y,z)$, and so on.  Doing this is looks like a very messy exercise, but it ends up with the following nice form:
$$
Q(x,y,z) = -(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)\left(\sum_{i+j+k=n-2}x^iy^jz^k\right)\;.
$$
Verifying that this multiplies out to $Q(x,y,z)$ is probably more elegant than the above direct factorization, but does require some care.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You can think $P(x,y,z)$ as a polynomial in $y$ , then see that $P(x,z,z)=0$. This means, $(y-z)$ divides $P(x,y,z)$, as we have done for polynomials in one variable. Similarly think about $P(y,y,z)$ and $P(z,y,z)$.

Comment: I was overcomplicating it. I didn't know if those were sufficient conditions. Thanks for explaing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

If at least 2 of the $x,y,z$ are equal then it is obvious. Eitherwise, You can consider $P$ as a polynomial of $x$ first and see that for $x=y,z$ we get $P=0$, so $$P=(x-y)(x-z)Q (1)$$, where $Q$ is a polynomial of $x$ with $z,y$ as parameters. Now consider $P$ as a polynomial of $z$. For $z=y$, we get again $P=0$, The last one due to $(1)$ leads to the fact that $Q(y)=0$, and so $Q=(z-y)R$, if you consider again $Q$ as a polynomial now of $z$. This concludes the proof.